# How to copy data from one OpenDJ server to another?

Tags: opendj, forgerock

How can one copy LDAP records from one OpenDJ server to another ?

Answer (score 1):

Run `/opendj/bin/export-ldif`, it will output an ldif file that containes everything on your directory server, you can use then `/opendj/bin/import-ldif` to import the exported data.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the same data, you can just copy OpenDJ data directory from one server to another. The path to OpenDJ data directory specified in `instance.loc` file.